# Windows 10 Upgrade dialog keeps closing immediately after launching

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

I have a (licensed, registered,valid) Windows 8.1 installation on a Parallels VM. I rarely use it but a few months ago the "get Windows 10" icon appeared - I had thought maybe a VM install wouldn't be eligible.

Yesterday I decided to get this install done, but everytime I click the Window icon on the charm/taskbar, the Windows 10 dialog pops up, says "please wait" for about one second, then closes.

Does anyone know why this might be and if I can get it working?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it closes, but if you owuld like to upgrade to Windows 10, you may take a try with the Media Creation Tool:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10

Download the install media and then perform the upgrade manually.

This should make it work.